# Ubuntu nautilus and gedit crashes on minimize

Tags: unity, nautilus, themes

I have seen similar questions about nautilus crashing when minimizing.
I have also run into the same problem.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with unity desktop.
When i click on the minimize button, nautilus and gedit crashes or freezes or does not minimize and turns into a weird layout.
This happens only with themes like numix or cenodark.
If i use themes like ambiance or radiance things work fine.

Also applications like gedit and nautilus crash, applications like chrome do not cause problems.

I am unable to find common denominator in all these issues, i think it has  something to do with gtk2 or gtk3.

When i have numix or cenodark themes this following errors show:

```
(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:2586:0: Expected a valid selector

(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3823:51: Expected ')' in color definition

(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:3900:62: Expected ')' in color definition

(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4139:22: Expected a length

(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4142:17: Expected a border style

(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4168:22: Expected a length

(unity-tweak-tool:17971): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:4171:17: Expected a border style
```

If i use ambiance or radiance themes none of these errors happen.

I have tried to disable window animations too but the errors still happen.

What is cause of these issues and how may i solve them. Please let me know if additional details are required.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, the problem was i had upgraded my gnome terminal by using the gnome3-staging ppa and had neither disabled nor purged it so when i added the ppas for the theme i got the wrong version and the wrong libraries which did not seem to play well with my unity.

After purging the ppa and downgrading packages, the issue was fixed.